# How to define dynamic array of int[2]?

Tags: c

At this moment I have this definition:

```
int pipefds[10][2];
```

But I want to calculate its size dynamically and have something like this:

```
int *pipefds[2] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int[2]));
```

Sorry, this questions seems to be stupid, but I need to ask.

Comment: Try `int (*pipefds)[2] = ...`

Comment: I'm probably missing something but ...int* pInt = (int*)malloc (calculated_width * calculated_height * sizeof( int) );

Comment: @newbie You can do it this way too, but there's no need, 'cause the inner dimension is a constant.